# WP_query : meta_key with custom rule for specific value

Tags: custom-field, wp-query, meta-value

I'm a bit stuck with a WP_Query code. Here it is :

```
$args = array(
      'post_type' => 'post',
      'meta_query'=> array(
          'key' => 'karma',
          'compare' => '>=',
          'value' => 0,
          'type' => 'numeric'),
        'posts_per_page' => 9,
        'meta_key' => 'karma',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'post__not_in' => $dont_show_me
    );
```

What I want to do :

Show all posts with karma >= 0 (it works fine with this code). BUT if there are posts with karma = 100 only show 3 of them + the rest of posts.

Examples : 9 posts with karma = 150, 133, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 33, 11.

I want to show: 150, 133, 100, 100, 100, 33, 11. (Only 3 posts with karma = 100 are allowed).

Do you have any idea how to achieve this?
Maybe a `add_filter('posts_where');` ?

UPDATE: Okay I got it working, based on @s_ha_dum answer. It's a bit tricky, but the result works ;)

```
$args = array(
       // Check for 9 last posts with karma = 100
       'post_type' => 'post',
       'meta_query'=> array(
          array(
              'key' => 'karma',
              'compare' => '=', 
              'value' => 100,
              'type' => 'numeric'
           )
        ),
       'posts_per_page' => 9,
       'meta_key' => 'karma',
       'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 
       'order' => 'DESC',
       'post__not_in' => $dont_show_me
    );
    $karma_qry = new WP_Query($args);

    if (!empty($karma_qry->posts)) {
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($karma_qry->posts as $p) {
            $i++;
            // Check for more than 3 posts with karma = 100
            // Add them in the $dont_show_me array 
            if($i > 3){
                $dont_show_me[] = $p->ID;
            }
        }
    }

    // Setup the final query that excluded addional posts with karma = 100
    $args['meta_query'][0]['compare'] = '>=';
    $args['meta_query'][0]['value'] = 0;
    $args['post__not_in'] = $dont_show_me;

    $wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `meta_query` is an array of arrays. Look at the [examples in the the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query).

```
 $args = array(
   'post_type' => 'my_custom_post_type',
   'meta_key' => 'age',
   'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
   'order' => 'ASC',
   'meta_query' => array(
       array(
           'key' => 'age',
           'value' => array(3, 4),
           'compare' => 'IN',
       )
   )
 );
 $query = new WP_Query($args);
```

What you have is just an array. That could be causing trouble. What you want to do is this:

```
$args = array(
   'post_type' => 'post',
   'meta_query'=> array(
      array(
          'key' => 'karma',
          'compare' => '>=', // limit to "karma value = 100"
          'value' => 0, // limit to "karma value = 100"
          'type' => 'numeric'
       )
    ),
   'posts_per_page' => 9,
   'meta_key' => 'karma',
   'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 
   'order' => 'DESC',
   'post__not_in' => $dont_show_me
);
```

However, to get to the question itself, you can't do logic as complicated as you need ...

> Show all posts with karma >= 0 (it works fine with this code). BUT if
>   there are posts with karma = 100 only show 3 of them + the rest of
>   posts.

... with a single `WP_Query`. That sounds like you want to pull 3, and only 3, posts with karma greater than 100, and fill in the rest with anything else. That would be tricky with pure SQL. I think it is possible in SQL but I would have to think a *lot* to be sure, much less to make it work.

I would suggest two queries-- one to get the "greater than 100" and a second to get the rest.

```
$dont_show_me = array(1);
$args = array(
   'post_type' => 'post',
   'meta_query'=> array(
      array(
          'key' => 'karma',
          'compare' => '>=', 
          'value' => 100,
          'type' => 'numeric'
       )
    ),
   'posts_per_page' => 3,
   'meta_key' => 'karma',
   'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 
   'order' => 'DESC',
   'post__not_in' => $dont_show_me
);
$karma_qry = new WP_Query($args);

if (!empty($karma_qry->posts)) {
  $args['posts_per_page'] = 9 - $karma_qry->found_posts;
  $args['meta_query'][0]['value'] = 0;
  foreach ($karma_qry->posts as $p) {
      // assuming $dont_show_me is an array
      $dont_show_me[] = $p->ID;
  }
  $args['post__not_in'] = $dont_show_me;
} else {
  $args['posts_per_page'] = 9;
  $args['meta_query'][0]['value'] = 0;
}

$the_rest_qry = new WP_Query($args);
```

I can't test that as I don't have your `karma` data on my server, but I am fairly sure that is correct. It ought to get you most of the way, at least.

Comment: Think you for your answer. But your code only show posts with karma = 100. I want to show all posts with karma >= 0 BUT if the post got karma = 100 only show 3 of them. (I'll edit my question).

Comment: @hawkidoki : see the edit.

Comment: Really interesting solution! For others people, there is an error near the end of your code $args['post__no_in'] (it's post__not_in).

Your solution seems to work, I got to tweak it a bit BTW, but the idea is great :) Think you very much!

Comment: @hawkidoki : I'll fix that error. Thanks. Both questions and answers are community edited here, like wiki. You can fix mistakes like that yourself.